# How to convert dsPIC33 HEX file to binary?

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader, pic, microchip, xc16

I have a HEX file for my application on dsPIC33, now I want to send the file over to microcontroller via serially.

As the HEX file generated by the compiler are intel hex format, I tried to convert it to binary with `arm-none-eabi-objcopy`, which, as expected does not work.

Is there any tool to convert HEX or ELF files to raw binary for dsPIC33?

Comment: The most flexible albeit with a bit of a learning curve, collection of tools IMHO is http://srecord.sourceforge.net/ . The [GNUmake Table Toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) can serve as a complement, closing the gap between configuration data regarding memory ranges, vector tables etc. and the pre- and post-processing of microcontroller binaries.

Comment: I had created a binary file with srec_cat command but it appends some additional bytes in the binary, maybe I had some incorrect options or I had done something incorrectly.
I'll study the links that you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the MPLAx IPE.

When you load your `.hex` file and bulid an environment you will get an `.bin` file,

Comment: What do you mean by building an environment ?

Comment: Just have a look at the MPLABx IPE. There ist a button Ènviroment`to save the firware e.g. on a SD card. Pretty easy to use.

Comment: My version of MPLAB IPE has an option to export the hex file only. I'll check if there is a newer version available.

Comment: Every version of the IPE could manage it. Just click huge button on the left side `Environment`. The one with the globe symbol.

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot @Mike!

Comment: I can do it with the GUI now and it does not need a Programmer attached. But, when I try to do it with ipecmd.jar with -B switch, it throws a message, 'Programmer not found', any way to do this without a programmer?

Answer (score 0):

So I have to look through/read .hex files on occasion, much easier when they are in .bin. If you have a linux host, install hex2bin, and then just simply execute "./hex2bin <filename.hex>", then use something like GHex to read through the file.